# How to configure PyCharm to use internal dir as module root?

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

I have the following structure (which is a standard structure for scrapy):

```
root/
    .git/
    scrapers/
        scrapers/
            __init__.py
            pipelines.py
            settings.py
        scrapy.cfg
    .gitignore
```

In `pipelines.py` I'm doing the following import:

```
from scrapers.settings import API_URL, API_KEY
```

The code works just fine! However, PyCharm marks this as an error, with a message `Cannot find reference 'settings' in 'imported module scrapers'`. It thinks that the outer `scrapers/` directory is the module root. It would incorrectly suggest that the correct import is:

```
from scrappers.scrapers.settings import API_URL, API_KEY
```

I tried marking the internal `scrapers/` directory as "sources root" and it didn't help. How can I configure PyCharm to assume the root for this code is in the internal `scrapers/` dir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically the inner `scrapers` dir is a python package, see [Packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

For Pycharm to be able to locate the package you'd need to configure its *parent* dir - the outer `scrapers` dir - as `Sources Root` (i.e. a dir where packages and maybe modules are found). From [Content root types](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/content-root.html#root_types):

> These roots contain the actual source files and resources. PyCharm
>   uses the source roots as the starting point for resolving imports.

Comment: Awesome! I had marked the internal directory as sources root, not the outer one. This fixed it.